# Image Problems when Adding a Facebook "Like" Button to an external page

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

I am trying to add the Facebook “Like” or “Recommend” button to the bottom of some of the content pages on our website, so that when someone clicks it, it is immediately posted on their FB wall - spreading the word about the page etc.

I found this code to do it:

```
<div id="fb-root">&nbsp;</div>
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#appId=174289559298553&amp;xfbml=1"></script>
<p><fb:like send="true" show_faces="true" action="recommend" font="arial" href="http://amathus.staging.screenpages.net/moillardproducerpage" width="450"></fb:like></p>
```

But when I put it on the page and test it by "liking/ recommending" it, when it feeds through to my facebook the image picked up to represent the page with the link is not good at all.

I then tried putting meta tags in the coding so that it picked up the right image, like this:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="Domaine Moillard" />
<meta property="og:type" content="drink" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://amathus.staging.screenpages.net/moillardproducerpage" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.amathusdrinks.com/skin/frontend/default/default/Agro-de-Bazanc.jpg" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Amathus Drinks" />
<meta property="fb:admins" content="61406146" />
```

But again the only images it picked up on were the small payment logo at the bottom (sagepay logo - not ideal!).

Anyone know how I can get it to show a relevant image next to the link when someone likes the page?

Thanks,

Clare

Answer (score 0):

I tried running http://amathus.staging.screenpages.net/moillardproducerpage thru the linter tool (https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) and nothing came up.  Is this the correct URL?

From the image url you gave above, I see it's from http://www.amathusdrinks.com/, so I ran http://www.amathusdrinks.com/moillardproducerpage thru the linter tool as well.  Got some results, but it has some issues to be fixed:

```
Inferred Property:  The og:url property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.
Inferred Property:  The og:title property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.
Inferred Property:  The og:image property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.
```

I'd say, fix the og: tags on that page, and you'll be back in business :)